# Cannot start Jenkins on https

Tags: jenkins, keystore, p12

I'm trying to switch `Jenkins` on `https` port,but i'm receiving the following errors and `Jenkins` cannot be started

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory
at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:209)
at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:150)
at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at Main._main(Main.java:312)
at Main.main(Main.java:136)
Caused by: winstone.WinstoneException: Error getting the SSL context object
at winstone.AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.getSSLContext(AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.java:216)
at winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory.createConnector(HttpsConnectorFactory.java:56)
at winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory.start(HttpsConnectorFactory.java:41)
at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:207)
... 8 more`
       Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetKey(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(Unknown Source)
at winstone.AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.getSSLContext(AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.java:183)
```

I created a new `keystore` and inside the `keystore` i have imported a `p12` certificate.
Probably something is wrong with the `keystore`? What `Jenkins` expects in the `keystore`? Do i need to import a public certificate in the `keystore`?

Comment: Did you look into `Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key` more?

Comment: Good point ! It turned out that the `keystore` password should be the same like the password of the `p12` `certificate`

Answer (score 7):

I also ran in to the this issue while having 2 different passwords for my p12 and jks. ( I started with a private key and a self signed certificate, then converted my key and cert in to a p12 format store, finally converted p12 to a jks file )

```
Caused by: winstone.WinstoneException: Error getting the SSL context object
        at winstone.AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.getSSLContext(AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.java:229)
        at winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory.start(HttpsConnectorFactory.java:63)
        at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:220)
        ... 8 more Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
        at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:315)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:143)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:57)
        at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:96)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:71)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023)
        at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:145)
        at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:70)
        at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:256)
        at winstone.AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.getSSLContext(AbstractSecuredConnectorFactory.java:190)
        ... 10 more 2021-03-27 05:38:15.911+0000 [id=1]     SEVERE  winstone.Logger#logInternal: Container startup failed java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
        at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:315)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:143)
        at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:57)
```

I applied the same password for p12 and jks and then attempted and could got rid or this error.

Comment: Thank you for this. This led to me realizing what the actual issue was. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I run into similar problem. I had Jenkins installation on RHEL. When I went through procedure to switch to https, got the same error.
Finally setting the same password to pkcs12 and then jks fixed the problem.

Comment: Your answer doesn't add anything new that wasn't already said in other answers